# FedCM get() rejects with NetworkError: Error retrieving a token

Tags: google-signin, fedcm

We tested our application for FedCM changes as mentioned in the Beta Test Program  https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/fedcm-migration.

Steps we followed:

1. Enabled the experimental FedCmWithoutThirdPartyCookies feature under chrome://flags.
2. Blocked the third party cookies in browser settings.
3. Have set use_fedcm_for_prompt to true in the IdConfiguration object.
4. We haven't used opt_out_or_no_session in our application.
5. We haven't used position style attributes from data-prompt_parent_id and intermediate_iframes in our application.
6. We have not defined CSP for our website.
7. We haven't used AMP support for our sign for our application.

After making these changes, we see the following:

1. The one tap prompt dialogue doesn't get displayed initially and throws a message '**Third-party sign in was disabled in browser Site Settings'**
2. After a minute we also see this error in the console - **'[GSI_LOGGER]: FedCM get() rejects with NetworkError: Error retrieving a token.'**
   **So basically we do not see the prompt dialogue.**

Is this issue related to **auto_select : true** in the IdConfigurationObject?? The one tap prompt dialogue did not seem to appear even when tried with commenting the **'auto_select : true'** parameter.

After making these changes, we see the following:

1. The one tap prompt dialogue doesn't get displayed initially and throws a message '**Third-party sign in was disabled in browser Site Settings'**
2. After a minute we also see this error in the console - **'[GSI_LOGGER]: FedCM get() rejects with NetworkError: Error retrieving a token.'**
   **So basically we do not see the prompt dialogue.**

Is this issue related to **auto_select : true** in the IdConfigurationObject?? The one tap prompt dialogue did not seem to appear even when tried with commenting the **'auto_select : true'** parameter.

Comment: I have the xact same error for some users - `[GSI_LOGGER]: FedCM get() rejects with NetworkError: Error retrieving a token` but enable to consistently reproduce 

Answer (score 1):

The One Tap does not display because your browser had the "Third-party sign-in" setting disabled. You can enable it by going to chrome://settings/content/federatedIdentityApi on your Chrome Browser.

[image]

Comment: I am getting error like [GSI_LOGGER]: FedCM get() rejects with IdentityCredentialError: Error retrieving a token.  and I do have this enabled 
Sites can show sign-in prompts from identity services.  I am testing FedCM with OneTap sign-in by adding data attribute data-use_fedcm_for_prompt='true'

Comment: For some reason, I had this disabled for a test site for which I was testing use_fedcm_for_prompt. It gets disabled if you close the prompt shown by Chrome